# Can we use "copies" to describe 2 things have slight differences?

Tags: expressions

In computer, we can copy one file as its copy. We can say them (2 copies of the file).

> To keep 2 copies of the file would be waste space.

Then, if one file has slight differences with the other one, but one of them is no longer useful.

Can I say

> To keep 2 copies of the file would be waste space.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the original sentence doesn't quite sound natural because the act of keeping isn't equivalent to "waste space". However, you could say

> To keep 2 copies of the file would **waste space**.
>
> To keep 2 copies of the file would be **to waste space**.
>
> To keep 2 copies of the file would be **a waste of space**.
>
> To keep 2 copies of the file would result in **wasted space**.

Second, if the second version isn't a copy of the first, then the reasoning no longer holds; you're not deleting the old version because it's a copy but because it isn't needed for another reason. In this case, you might say, for example,

> To keep an obsolete version of the file wastes space.
>
> It's a waste of space to keep an old version of the file.
>
> It wastes space to keep an out-of-date file.
>
> Space is wasted by keeping multiple versions of a file.